# Sometimes I find that the Do Not Disturb feature is off, but I did not turn it off

Tags: iphone, ios

I am not sure what I am missing.  I turned the feature on, then went into Notifications, set it up.  The moon icon appears in the top status bar and then the next day (or day after), the icon is gone.  I go back into Settings and sure enough, the feature is OFF.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a schedule set (in Settings > Notifications > Do Not Disturb)? The Do Not Disturb slider will be switched to off automatically outside the scheduled period.

Comment: @binarybob Correct, it should be switched off outside the scheduled period (11:59 PM to 7:00 AM).  The problem is that doesn't switch back on the next day.